# Post Processing Removes Lens Flares and Causes error: copyTexImage2D: framebuffer is incompatible format

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Given the lens flares example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lensflares,

Why am I not able to post process this scene correctly? The blocks will all show up correctly but the light sources and the lens flares are gone and I get a bunch of warnings in the console stating:  copyTexImage2D: framebuffer is incompatible format. I have all the same code except for the following snippets added to the `init()` and `render()` loop:

```
// init()
// 
// Post Processing (
// 
var rtParameters = {
  minFilter:     THREE.LinearFilter,
  magFilter:     THREE.LinearFilter,
  format:        THREE.RGBFormat,
  stencilBuffer: true
 };

// Vignette scene.
var shaderVignette = THREE.VignetteShader;
var effectVignette = new THREE.ShaderPass(shaderVignette);
effectVignette.uniforms[ "offset" ].value = 0.95;
effectVignette.uniforms[ "darkness" ].value = 1.6;

// What are these??
var clearMask = new THREE.ClearMaskPass();
var renderMask = new THREE.MaskPass(scene, camera);

effectVignette.renderToScreen = true;

// Render entire scene as a texture. 
var renderModel = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
// renderModel.clear = false;

// Notice: Takes *entire* canvas. 
composerScene = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer,
  new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, rtParameters));
composerScene.addPass(renderModel);
composerScene.addPass(clearMask);

// Not sure what this does... renderTarget2 is the buffer we read from...
renderScene = new THREE.TexturePass(composerScene.renderTarget2);

// Add first composer -- don't add any passes except for renderScene. 
composer1 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer,
  new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width / 2, height, rtParameters));
composer1.addPass(renderScene);
composer1.addPass(effectVignette);

// Add second composer -- do image processing passes here. 
composer2 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer,
  new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width / 2, height, rtParameters));
composer2.addPass(renderScene);
composer2.addPass(effectVignette);

renderScene.uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = composerScene.renderTarget2;
```

Then within in my render loop, I have the following:

```
//render() 
// Set view port to entire region
renderer.setViewport(0, 0, width, height);

renderer.clear();
composerScene.render(delta);

// Render original scene. 
renderer.setViewport(0, 0, width / 2, height);
composer1.render(delta);

// Render modified scene. 
renderer.setViewport(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);
composer2.render(delta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was in this line:

```
// Notice: Takes *entire* canvas. 
composerScene = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer,
  new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, rtParameters));
```

Since I have dividing the scene into two different sections, width should be width/2. So the corrected code is:

```
// Notice: Takes only the size of the image we want to render. 
composerScene = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer,
  new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width/2, height, rtParameters));
```

Please note: This had nothing to do with lens flares. The issue was much more fundamental. Sorry about that!!